# Вживання слів "відносно", "стосовно", "щодо", "з приводу"

Tags: вживання-слів, росіянізм

Протягом певного часу, стежачи за мовою колег, друзів, прислухаючись до радіо- і теленовин, або ж звернувши увагу на писемну мову найрізноманітніших жанрів. Можна засвідчити, що функціонування цих синонімічних прийменників є досить активним. І — доволі проблематичним, стилістично "підступним". Бо не завжди вони уживаються доречно. Досить поширеною помилкою стає скальковане з російської "относительно" слововживання відносно:

> "Обговорено акти національного законодавства відносно охорони
>   навколишнього середовища";
>
> "Було прийнято остаточне рішення відносно транзиту газу".

Але ж за нормами державної мови у таких випадках варто вживати слова "стосовно" та "щодо":

СУМ-11 [пояснює](http://sum.in.ua/s/shhodo):

> **ЩО́ДО**, прийм., з род. в. Стосовно до кого-, чого-небудь, відносно когось, чогось. *Олексій Максимович намагався помогти мені щодо російської мови* (Коцюб., III, 1956, 430);
>
> // З приводу чого-небудь. *Щодо мого наміру вступити в монастир, то справа стояла так* (Коцюб., III, 1956,292);
>
> // Про, за когось, щось. *Говорив з ним [начальством] щодо чергових місяців. Згодилися, що знов поїду на весняні місяці і знов в Алупку* (Коцюб., III, 1956, 143);
>
> // Уживається для вираження особливостей, властивостей, якості кого-, чого-небудь, які характеризуються з боку тих або інших ознак, зв’язків, стосунків і т. ін. *Поема [І. Франка "Мойсей"] багатогранна і щодо ідейного змісту, і щодо форми* (Від давнини… І, 1960, 469).
>
> **Що́до** *кого — чого*, **то**… — якщо говорити про кого-, що-небудь, мати на увазі кого-, що-небудь, то..; а стосовно до кого-, чого-небудь, то… *Щодо самого Ренана, то деякі студенти, мені відомі, його читають і що З того читання виносять, того не знаю, бо якось се ні в чім не виражається* (Л. Укр., V, 1956, 142).

Отож ужиті у вказаних ситуаціях синонімічні прийменники "щодо" та "стосовно" загалом є взаємозамінними: обидва слова мають виразне забарвлення книжності, підкресленої офіційності.

Вислів "по відношенню до…" зумовлений невдалим наслідуванням російського "по отношению к...", для української мови є грубою помилкою:

> "По відношенню до України скасовано візовий режим";
>
> "по відношенню до зарубіжних партнерів".

адже [згідно](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) СУМ-11:

> **ВІДНО́ШЕННЯ**, я, с. 1. Стосунок, причетність до кого-, чого-небудь; зв’язок з кимсь, чимсь.
>
> *У (такому-то) відно́шенні — маючи на увазі певну сторону явища, предмета тощо; розглядаючи з певного боку, з певної точки зору.

Отже наведених конструкцій варто уникати, послуговуючись прийменниками "стосовно", "щодо" (стосовно України, щодо зарубіжних партнерів)?

Чи не є вживання прийменника "з приводу", як наприклад: «Думки, що висловлювались з цього приводу, були найрізноманітніші" русизмом?

Адже відповідно до [пояснень](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4) СУМ-11:

> **ПРИ́ВІД**, воду, ч.
>   1. Підстава (справжня або вигадана), причина яких-небудь дій, вчинків.
>   Дава́ти (да́ти) при́від кому, чому для чого, з інфін. — створювати підстави для певних дій, вчинків, думок і т. ін.

Чи вірні зроблені висновки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

СУМ-20.

[Відносно](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=13222&page=432):

> у знач. **прийм., з род. в.** **Те саме**, що **що́до**. – Тепер маю до тебе прохання відносно .. Дерижанових (Леся Українка);

СУМ-11.

[Щодо](http://sum.in.ua/s/shhodo):

> ЩОДО, **прийм., з род. в.** **Стосовно** до кого-, чого-небудь, відносно
>   когось, чогось.

[Стосовно](http://sum.in.ua/s/stosovno):

> **СТОСО́ВНО**, **прийм. з род. в.**, у сполуч. з прийм. до. У **відповідності** з
>   чим-небудь; у застосуванні до чогось.

[З приводу](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryvid):

> **З приводу** чого, якого — у **зв'язку** з чим-небудь. Напишу тобі ще кілька
>   слів про своє, здоров'я, бо не хочу, щоб ти турбувалася з приводу тої
>   звістки, яку я подав учора (Михайло Коцюбинський, III, 1956, 347);

Отже, всі ці слова - словникові. *Відносно*, *стосовно*, *щодо* є хоч не повними, але синонімами. *З приводу* - не росіянізм, бо також словникове (до того ж, його у своїх творах використовував М. Коцюбинський). Те саме з *відносно* (словникове і вживала Л. Косач).